# MYSQL select count two table left join

Tags: performance, sql, mysql

I have two table. I want count how many times a value is in other table. So the codice from table "sorgente" is different in table contatore, because I have the suffix 'BRANO-' before the code.

```
sorgente
| codice | nome  |
|   15   | mario |
|   16   | mary  |

contatore
| nome_evento |   data     |
| BRANO-15    | 2020-08-15 |
| BRANO-15    | 2020-08-16 |
| BRANO-16    | 2020-08-14 |
```

the query for select is

```
select
    s.codice,
    (
        select count(*) 
        from contatore c 
        where c.nome_evento = concat('BRANO-', s.codice) 
    ) no_matches_in_contatore
from sorgente s
```

but the original "sorgente" table has 25000 records, the "contatore" table has at now 60000 records.
when I try to execute the query it takes 600 seconds....
can you help me?

Comment: let me know what indexes are on your tables.

Comment: Please read the [SQL tag wiki's guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/sql/info) for requesting SQL reviews: 1) Provide context, 2) Include the schema, 3) If asking about performance, include indexes and the output of EXPLAIN SELECT.

Comment: It needs `GROUP BY s.codice` at the end.